# How to bind FAB to Bottom Navigation Bar from outer layout?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

How to bind FAB to Bottom Navigation Bar from outer layout?
I want to to bind FAB to Bottom Navigation Bar in such way that when user is scrolling up and Bottom Navigation Bar is hiding (by scrolling down) I want my FAB to scroll down together with Bottom Navigation Bar. And I have one layout (parent layout) with `BottomNavigationView` (activity_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content Container -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_bar_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start|end"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:elevation="@dimen/bottom_navigation_bar_elevation"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Abd I have the following fragment_day.xml with FAB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/header_padding">

        ...  

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_bottom_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/md_keylines"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/fabs_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_large_diameter" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And when it looks like this, while user is scrolling, only `BottomNavigationView` is moving, but FAB remains stationary.

I've tried also to add the following line to `<FloatingActionButton>` tag:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/fabs_on_scroll_behavior"
```

and the following line to strings.xml:
com.example.view.utils.FABScrollingViewBehavior

where this `com.example.view.utils.FABScrollingViewBehavior` class is actually `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` + `HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior`:

```
public class FABScrollingViewBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    protected static final int ENTER_ANIMATION_DURATION = 225;
    protected static final int EXIT_ANIMATION_DURATION = 175;
    private static final int STATE_SCROLLED_DOWN = 1;
    private static final int STATE_SCROLLED_UP = 2;
    private int height = 0;
    private int currentState = 2;
    private ViewPropertyAnimator currentAnimator;

    public FABScrollingViewBehavior() {
    }

    public FABScrollingViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent,
                                 FloatingActionButton child,
                                 int layoutDirection) {
        this.height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
    }

    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                       FloatingActionButton child,
                                       View directTargetChild,
                                       View target,
                                       int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == 2;
    }

    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                               FloatingActionButton child, View target,
                               int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                               int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        if(this.currentState != 1 && dyConsumed > 0) {
            this.slideDown(child);
        } else if(this.currentState != 2 && dyConsumed < 0) {
            this.slideUp(child);
        }

    }

    protected void slideUp(FloatingActionButton child) {
        if(this.currentAnimator != null) {
            this.currentAnimator.cancel();
            child.clearAnimation();
        }

        this.currentState = 2;
        this.animateChildTo(child, 0, 225L, AnimationUtils.LINEAR_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
    }

    protected void slideDown(FloatingActionButton child) {
        if(this.currentAnimator != null) {
            this.currentAnimator.cancel();
            child.clearAnimation();
        }

        this.currentState = 1;
        this.animateChildTo(child, this.height, 175L, AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_LINEAR_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
    }

    private void animateChildTo(FloatingActionButton child, int targetY, long duration, TimeInterpolator interpolator) {
        this.currentAnimator = child.animate().translationY((float)targetY).setInterpolator(interpolator).setDuration(duration).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                FABScrollingViewBehavior.this.currentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But in this case only FAB is moving down by scrolling, and BottomNavigationView remains stationary. How to bind this FAB to BottomNavigationBar so that they will move together?

Answer (score 1):

try this this will work for me

```
int oldPostion = 0

myScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            if (myScrollView.getScrollY() > oldPostion) {
                myfab.hide();
            } else if (myScrollView.getScrollY() < oldPostion || myScrollView.getScrollY() <= 0) {
                myfab.show();
            }
            oldPostion = myScrollView.getScrollY();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Kubal, thank you! But where should I place this code?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me (